# dotnet ef Failed to load /snap/dotnet-sdk/168/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.5/libcoreclr.so (using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Tags: .net, ubuntu-22.04

after install dotnet ef success in ubuntu 22.04 LTS, i have problem when running dotnet ef in terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXWJr.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved Problem dotnet ef in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**

***1. First Way***

i am uninstalling all data with following documentation .net

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-linux#uninstall-net

**open your terminal :**

sudo apt-get remove dotnet-host

**# adjust to your .net version**

version="1.0.1"

sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/$version

sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$version

sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/$version

sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/$version

sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr/$version

after deleting all, install again dotnet-sdk and runtime with followed documentation :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

***2. Second Way***

i am remove dotnet-sdk from directory project, with command :

sudo snap remove dotnet-sdk

running again command :

dotnet ef

**if you are confused please show image**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DiNB.png